# Accessing Firebase with 'user authentication' active using Powershell

Tags: powershell, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a client side app using JavaScript connected to a Firebase database where a user can login and save/edit some data stored Firebase. 'Email and Password' authentication is used as https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

I subsequently wanted to write a Powershell script which would be setup with 'Task Scheduler' to run 1x per day, read each users data and execute some business logic.

I incorrectly expected to be able to whitelist my Server IP to get full access rights to the DB.

If I understood it correctly I need to use 'Custom authentication' using 'JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)', but there are no helper libraries available for Powershell. Had a look at this section https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-tokens-without-helpers but it's not clear to me what needs to be done to get the token.

Can someone give me some pointers or sample code on how to get JWT to work with Firebase/Powershell, or some alternate ways I can get full access to the BD using Powershell?

Thanks in advance

Quintus

Comment: PowerShell is .NET isn't it? So you can just compile the Firebase .NET helper and use that to generate JWTs. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-dotNet

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'm however not familiar with Visual Studio or how to run .NET inside Powershell scripts, so I'm still kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that might help you ...

```
#region TokenGenerator

function TokenGeneretor($secret){

$asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\Firebase\FirebaseTokenGenerator.dll")
$tokenGenerator =  [Firebase.TokenGenerator]::new("$secret")
$authPayload = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.Object]"
$authPayload.Add('uid', '1')
$authPayload.Add('some', 'arbitrary')
$authPayload.Add('data', 'here')
$Option = [Firebase.TokenOptions]::new(((Get-Date).AddHours(1)),$null,$true)
$token = $tokenGenerator.CreateToken($authPayload, $Option)

return $token

}



#endregion
```

TokenGeneretor -secret "123"

The DLL mentioned is the code compiled from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-dotNet. Just open the project in Visual Studio and have it compiled. It will play the DLL in the project's DEBUG folder.